# STAssertEquals for checking NSArray count - clean way

Tags: objective-c, ocunit

What is the correct way to check the NSArray items count with STAssertEquals for NSArray.

Following was expected to work:

```
...
STAssertEquals(1, [myArray count], @"One item should be in array");
```

This code produces "Type mismatch" runtime error when running test.

Instead I have to do an explicit cast to NSUInteger:

```
STAssertEquals((NSUInteger)1, [myArray count], @"One item should be in array");
```

This works - but looks kind a ugly due to explicit cast.

I also want to avoid using STAssertTrue because STAssertEquals looks more appropriate (we compare two values) and shows the actual and expected values.

What is correct way to check it in Objective-C?

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks for the answers suggested to use 1u as unsigned int literal

```
STAssertEquals(1u, [myArray count], @"One item should be in array");
```

But as @Aaron mentioned it still ugly - I would like to use "1" directly - thinking on using myArray.count == 1 instead now. And the reason for it is that 1u doesn't look very clean. The 1 is 1 for me. You never write 1u in math :-) Any other suggestions?

**UPDATE 2**

As @H2CO3 mentioned 1u even could not always work and as suggested in some thread we could use more declarative definition for expected value which will solve the problem of casting:

```
NSUInteger expectedItemsCount = 1;
STAssertEquals(expectedItemsCount, [myArray count], @"One item should be in array");
```

I prefer it to 1u solution because it looks cleaner. But the cons of this approach is that we have extra line and code is not very compact. So it looks like we have to choose between two approaches: `(NSUInteger)1` and `NSUInteger expectedItemsCount = 1;`

Comment: Interesting, this means you have the flag `CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_IMPLICIT_CONVERSION` turned on, did you do that yourself (or somebody on the project) or did a recent Xcode update turn that one on? I thought it was off by default.

Comment: @Pascal OP doesn't get a compiler warning - he gets a **runtime** error.

Comment: @Pascal Yeah, another "Apple, WTF are you doing" in the system... :'(

Comment: Actually, @aaron-golden further down pointed out that "The STAssertEquals macro explicitly checks the type of the arguments and complains if the types are not equal". **That** would make sense then.

Comment: @Pascal - yeah it happens in runtime as I see after build succeeded. I didn't make any specific changes to the project and using XCode Version 4.6 (4H127)

Comment: After Aaron pointed out that `STAssertEquals` checks the type it makes sense. A simple `1` is an int to llvm, and an int is not the same type as NSUInteger of course. I would just cast the thing to let llvm know what you want.

Comment: and now , that explains my answer being down voted ;) thanks for the clarification

Comment: @JonReid why did you remove iOS tag? I think it's quite related to iOS. Could you add it back - I think it could benefit other iOS developers.

Comment: @Vladimir Because this applies to all Objective-C. There's nothing iOS specific.

Comment: @JonReid Okay - agree. Formally it's correct. We don't use iOS classes in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C's type system...

`1` is `int`, so it's signed. `NSArray.count` is `NSUInteger` so it's unsigned. Make the integer literal unsigned:

```
STAssertEquals(myArray.count, 1u, @"+1 item needed");
```

**Edit:** Even better, the above will fail on 64-bit (it would work with `1ull` there), so what if you just use something like

```
const NSUInteger expectedLength = 1;
STAssertEquals(myArray.count, expectedLength, @"+1 item needed");
```

[(The thread from where I stole this...)](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/307490-stassertequals-and-type-checking.html)

Comment: The second version seems a bit over the top for me, I would just cast the thing.

Comment: @Pascal It's nicer than casting. (In C, everything is better than casting.)

Comment: Also for literals? I assumed that in these cases it would hint the compiler what to do so it would use the correct types.

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks for elaboration on it. The info in the thread definitely help to understand in what boat we are :-) So now for myself I choose either one solution in Update 2.

Comment: @Pascal You're right - the compiler sometimes performs implicit conversions. It's this **stupid assertion macro** that doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `STAssertEquals(1U, myArray.count, @"One item should be in array");` to make the 1 unsigned.  Maybe that's still ugly.  It's a little bit less typing.

Answer (score 1):

1U is correct. But if you want to avoid that ugliness (and step into a better world of assertions), use OCHamcrest:

```
assertThat(myArray, hasCountOf(1));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. What is it? Hamcrest? I don't want to use extra library here and use standard tools instead. Also hasCountOf looks quite weird when you want to compare two values. I never saw this approach in other langs like Ruby or Java. But thanks for pointing that out - it's good to know all possible solutions.

Comment: Hamcrest was born in Java and is now a standard part of JUnit.

Comment: thanks for mentioning it then - I didn't try to use it even in Java. Will look then!

Answer (score 0):

If your project is substantial, or you expect this code to have a long life, consider adding specific assertions for things like this.  Define a special-case macro

```
  STArrayCount(myArray,1)
```

which can expand to something like

```
  STAssertTrue(myArray.count==1u,@"Expected %u but array count is %u",myArray.count,1);
```

Writing custom assertions makes your unit test clearer when you revisit it in a few years, and also provides a hook for additional testing. Suppose today myArray is an NSArray, but sometime later it becomes an instance of BigFancyObject that does some other things.  BigFancyObjects make most of your code much cleaner and hide implementation details, so that's all great. But you'd like to be sure that the BigFancyObject is valid because something keeps invalidating them.  So, you can redefine STArrayCount to

```
  STAssertTrue(myArray.isValid && myArray.count==...)
```

and now your unit tests check the object's validity, too.

Comment: Hi @MarkBernstein. I think it adds extra complexity to create special macro to check array count. We would use the operations we already have rather than define our own math :-)

Comment: Of course, if you're only doing this occasionally, you wouldn't want your own macro!  But in general it's a broadly useful technique. For details, see Meszaros' book on xUnit Test Patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is to compare them as objects, which will work on 32 & 64 bit, prevent the need for any casting or unnecessary variable declarations, and maintain a nice failure message that includes the failed values:

```
STAssertEqualObjects(@(5), @(datas.count), @"unexpected array count");
```